# Adding multiple AD Group/OU containers in Powershell script

Tags: api, powershell

I have an Active Directory sync script to add members of a group to a web application. I have in the script this portion:

```
 # user group to sync with management console
$syncGroupCN = "Group"
$syncGroupOU = "Hosting OU"
$syncGroupSearchFilter = "(&(objectCategory=user (memberOf=cn=$syncGroupCN,ou=$syncGroupOU,$nou$dn))"
```

I know how to nest the OU's with this portion:

```
    # user group to sync with management console
$syncGroupCN = "TeamViewerUsers"
$syncGroupOU = "Security Groups" <- OU where the group is. 
$syncGroupSearchFilter = "(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=cn=$syncGroupCN,ou=$syncGroupOU,ou=NewOU,ou=NewOU1,ou=NewOU2,$dn))" always from lower OU to higher OU
```

but can anyone point me in the right direction to add multiple groups from different OU's?

The script is located below:

```
# API access token 
$accessToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" #<-- your access token, can be left empty when OAuth (below) is configured.

# domain settings
$dn = "dc=domain,dc=local"

# ldap settings
$dcIP = "127.0.0.1"
$dcLdapPort = "389"

# user group to sync with management console
$syncGroupCN = "tvuser"
$syncGroupOU = "tvusers"
$syncGroupSearchFilter = "(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=cn=$syncGroupCN,ou=$syncGroupOU,$dn))"

# new user defaults (if not available in csv import file)
$defaultUserLanguage = "en"   
$defaultUserPassword = "myInitalPassword!"
$defaultUserPermissions = "ShareOwnGroups,EditConnections,EditFullProfile,ViewOwnConnections"

# deactivate company users not found in the configured AD group 
$deactivateUnknownUsers = $false
# testRun needs to be set to false for the script to perform actual changes
$testRun = $true

##########
# includes
##########

$currentPath = Split-Path ((Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 0).Value).MyCommand.Path

. (Join-Path $currentPath "Common.ps1")

###########
# Functions
###########

# Returns the AD members of the configured usergroup from above
function GetADMembersOfOU()
{
    Write-Host 
    Write-Host "Reading AD OU members"

    $result2 = $NULL

    try
    {
        $domain = "LDAP://" + $dcip + ":" + $dcLdapPort + "/$dn"
        $root = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry $domain

        $query = new-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
        $query.searchroot = $root        
        $query.Filter = $syncGroupSearchFilter

        #needed user properties
        $colProplist = "name", "mail", "givenName", "sn", "department", "description", "userAccountControl"

        foreach ($i in $colPropList)
        {
            [void]$query.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i)
        }    

        $result2 = $query.findall()

        $userDict = @{}

        foreach ($objResult in $result2)
        {
            $user = @{}

            $user["email"] = [string]$objResult.Properties.mail
            $user["name"] = [string]($objResult.Properties.givenname + $objResult.Properties.sn)

            #check user account status (00000000000000000000000000000010 binary, 2 decimal, UF_ACCOUNT_DISABLE)
            $uacVal = $objResult.Properties.useraccountcontrol.Item(0)
            $userEnabled = (($uacVal -BAND 2) -eq 0)

            #skip user when required fields are missing, or account is disabled
            if($user.email.length -gt 0 -and $user.name.length -gt 0 -and $userEnabled -eq $true)
            {
                $userDict.Add([PSCustomObject]$user.email, [PSCustomObject]$user)
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host "AD user is missing name and/or email. Skipped."
            }
        }


        $result2 = $userDict
    }
    catch [Exception]
    {
        Write-Host ("AD read failed! The error was '{0}'." -f $_)
        $result2 = $NULL
    }

        return $result2

}

#######################################
# Sync AD Usergroup with TeamViewer API
#######################################

if($testRun -eq $true)
{
    Write-Host "testRun is set to true. Information in your TeamViewer account will not be modified. Instead, all changes that would be made are displayed on the console. Press any key to continue..."
    $x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
}
Write-Host ("Starting AD OU Sync...")

# check OAuth requirements
if ($clientId -and $authorizationCode) 
{
    #get token
        $token = RequestOAuthAccessToken $clientId $clientSecret $authorizationCode
    if ($token){
        $accessToken = $token
    }
}

#ping API to check connection and token
if (PingAPI($accessToken) -eq $true)
{
    #read users from the AD OU  
    $dictUsersAD = GetADMembersOfOU

    #get all current users of our company from the API
    $arrUsersAPI = GetAllUsersAPI $accessToken

    #put all current API users in a dictionary, id field as key
    $dictUsersAPI = @{}
    foreach ($u in $arrUsersAPI)
    {
        #Write-Host $u.id
        $dictUsersAPI.Add($u.id, $u)    
    }

    #sync
    #for each user in AD group: check against API if user exists (by mail)  
    foreach($usrKey in $($dictUsersAD.keys))
    {
        #Write-Host $usrKey

        $userApi = $null
        $userAD = $null

        $userAD = $dictUsersAD[$usrKey]
        $userApi = GetUserByMail $accessToken $usrKey #lookup API user by mail  

        if($userApi) #user found -> update user
        { 
            Write-Host
            Write-Host "User with email=" $usrKey " found."

            if ($testRun -eq $true)
            {
                Write-Host "UpdateUser: " $usrKey " with this values:"
                $userAD | Foreach-Object {
                    Write-Host $_.Key " = " $_.Value
                }
                Write-Host
                $dictUsersAPI.Remove($userApi.id)
            }
            else
            {
            #Update the user
            UpdateUser $accessToken $userApi.id $userAD
            #remove this user from our dictionary
            $dictUsersAPI.Remove($userApi.id)
            }
        }
        else #no user found -> create user
        {
            Write-Host
            Write-Host "No user with email=" $usrKey " found."

            if ($testRun -eq $true)
            {
                Write-Host "CreateUser: " $usrKey " with this values:"
                $userAD | Foreach-Object {
                    Write-Host $_.Key " = " $_.Value
                }
                Write-Host
            }
            else
            {
            #Create User
            CreateUser $accessToken $userAD $defaultUserPermissions $defaultUserLanguage $defaultUserPassword
            }
        }       
    }

    # if configured, delete all users not in AD group
    if ($deactivateUnknownUsers -eq $true)
    {
        if ($testRun -eq $true)
        {
            Write-Host "Deactivate Unknown Users:"
            #$dictUsersAPI.GetEnumerator() | Foreach-Object {
            #   Write-Host "DeactivateUser: id = " $_.Key " name = " $_.Value["name"]
            #}
            foreach( $id in $($dictUsersAPI.Values))
            {
                Write-Host "DeactivateUser: id = " $id.id " name: " $id.name
            }
            Write-Host
        }
        else
        {
            #all users remaining in dictUsersAPI dictionary are not present in the AD group an can be deactivated
            foreach( $id in $($dictUsersAPI.Keys))
            {
                DeactivateUser $accessToken $id     
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    Write-Host ("No data imported. Token or connection problem.")
}

Write-Host ("AD OU Sync finished.")
```

Comment: You might want to include a little more of your code, three variables without any context as to what they are used by isn't really enough to be able to help. A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is really best.

Comment: Thanks for the comment James. I have edited the original request with the full script.